# Want to add different RadTabs in existing RadTab of RadTabStrip

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

I am adding different RadTabs in existing tab of RadTabStrip dynamically, but i am unable to see the tabs in existing tab.

Can you please provide me the proper solution on above scenario.?

Thanks and Regards,
Pradip.

Answer (score 0):

You may get a better result if you data bind the list instead:

```
tabList.DataSource = new[]
{
  new { Text = "1", Value = "1" },
  new { Text = "2", Value = "2" }
};
tabList.DataBind();
```

Map the text and value accordingly.